# Ethereum Keystore File Encrypted or Corrupted?

Tags: keystore, ethereum, geth

it seems that I accidentally deleted my Ethereum Keystore Directory. After the initial panic I ran a data recovery program which might have been able to recover the UTC--... file. Unfortunately, the account is not shown with
  `geth account list`
although I copied the UTC--... file into the keystore directory. Up to now I only mined and did not spend any ETH so I am not sure how to access the account and transfer my ETH. I remember that I created my account in mid of 2017 with
    `geth account new`
set a password and then started to mine on nanopool. Did I do already something wrong back then?

For testing I created a new account and its UTC-... file is proper JSON. The file I have recovered seems to be encrypted or corrupted since it is showing 31 lines of hex code in sublime. Since the file has the correct size I do not know whether it might be somehow only encrypted or wrongly encoded? Any ideas how I can get access to my mined ETH?

Any help would be appreciated :-)

**Update:** The keystore file looks like that (I omitted a few rows):

```
6588 5c1c dd47 c175 6ede 6c4f ba64 1106
f596 f45b 71af 9f2d 8728 8619 5873 9582
a8e0 837c 8a41 c65c e46d dbb6 af44 9ec8
56e6 f749 aefa dbd7 5e54 e053 260b fe54
38b7 07c4 9548 3a68 2fa6 201c 763d 3b32
1467 5c0c 8bc7 0285 2a48 aaca 81a8 e282
5ffe e88d f560 5364 7f97 d03c fb1f 3faa
5d8c 4b75 1a52 ed17 703a 99c2 be39 4b6f
3e0a 10c6 9250 458f 7d06 f7c5 baa3 5caa
4513 f942 fa56 bc62 40b6 44bb f61c d608
...
d42f 3d78 06b7 d5d5 44f1 6b0d 7573 cc92
c888 323b 083a e43f b6cc 8728 6285 424f
1a45 41f1 4d8d 5ea5 7eb7 2299 e2ec 3a3b
fd17 9f0e 92be 7f1e 7909 a8cc 8f42 20b5
869a bdfb 9734 1f45 690c 67
```

Comment: One option is to use something like this python API to confirm that you can decrypt the keyfile: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#extract-private-key-from-geth-keyfile

Comment: This results in the following error message:'  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)'

Comment: Looks like it may be corrupted, then, since it doesn't appear to be valid JSON after decryption.